# matlab - Full Multivariate polynomial function plot

Tags: matlab, polynomials

hi I have a question related to full polynomial function of two variables. I can write code to calculate the value of it but I dont know how to plot the contour at level 0. For example: given a full 5th-order polynomial

f(x,y) = theta1 + theta2*x + theta3*y + theta4*x*y + theta5*x^2 + theta6*y^2 + ... + theta20*x^5 + theta21*y^5

I already wrote the code to compute f(x,y) given theta, x and y but how can I plot this function

theta1 + theta2*x + theta3*y + theta4*x*y + theta5*x^2 + theta6*y^2 + ... + theta20*x^5 + theta21*y^5 = 0 ?

thank you!

Comment: You can try `ezcontour` and adjust the `caxis` to plot the 0 contour line.

Comment: This seems more of a mathematical than programming issue to me. The intersection of your 2D function and a plane (in your case one that is defined by the x and y axis) can be found in many ways, whether it be analytically, algebraically or numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your function takes values element wise.  If not, declare a function handle that takes in the variables `x` and `y` that represent the values in those respective dimensions:

```
f = @(x,y) theta1 + theta2*x + theta3*y + theta5*x.^2 + theta6*y.^2 + ... + theta24*x.^5 + theta25*y.^5;
```

(.... do you need to have that many `theta` values?).  Next, generate a domain of `x` and `y` coordinates that you wish to plot. You can do that with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:0.01:10);
```

This generates a grid of `(x,y)` coordinates between -10 to 10 for both dimension in steps of 1.

Now, generate your `Z` coordinates by using the above function:

```
Z = f(X,Y);
```

Now that you're finally done, use the [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) function with `X,Y` and `Z`.  Now, if you want to show just the level where `f(x,y) = 0`, you specifically need to do this:

```
contour(X,Y,Z,[0 0]);
```

In general, the fourth element takes in a vector of contour levels but if you want to specifically draw one level, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yes I need all of the `theta` because it is supposed to be a polynomial having full terms. And I have another question: 
I need actually to draw the full polynomial functions with orders ranging from 1 to 5. So I want to write a function to sketch the polynomial whose input is the desired order of it (like the one I wrote to calculate its value but I dont have any idea to make it plot the figure). Can I actually do that? if yes please give me some hints.

Comment: That's going to be difficult because you need to know how many `theta` are generated as well as the actual `theta` parameters themselves given the order and these must be provided before creating the handle.  You can't write a single anonymous function to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess there's no way other than writing down the full function. See you then.